# Manhwa where a woman transfered to a medieval world builds a metal boat

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

I’m looking for a manhwa that has a female character reincarnating into the typical medieval world of nobles and I think it is a typical romance genre. The character, at some point, makes a bet with another powerful noble saying that she can build a metal boat that can float, which she knows is possible because of her knowledge from her previous live. She then also proves this assumption by building a small model out of metal and presenting the results in front of a crowd. If I remember correctly, she goes on to be sponsored by the king/emperor to build such ship on a large scale and also goes to supervise their building process.

If anyone could give me the title of that manhwa, I’d be very grateful! :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F. Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Honestly I do not remember. I think I read it on the comick.cc website, but I only recently switched to that website, so it could be possible I read it elsewhere.